# Use container's environment variable for a command lie

Tags: bash, docker

I would like to use some environment variables in a bash script that contains :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker-compose exec apache bash -c "\
    printenv | grep BLACKFIRE\
    && blackfire-agent --register --server-id=$BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID --server-token=$BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN \
    && /etc/init.d/blackfire-agent restart"
echo "Blackfire agent configured !"
```

I pass the variable from my .env :

```
BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID=xxxxx
BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN=xxxxx
BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID=xxxxx
BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN=xxxxx
```

using docker-compose.yml

```
environment:
  - DAMART_ENV=dev
  - BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID=${BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID}
  - BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN=${BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN}
  - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID}
  - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN}
```

The apache container has the environment variables (here is the result of printenv)

[image]

If I change the variables by their values it works but I don't want to use them directly in this script.

How should I call the variables for them to work.

Comment: Can you not just build the container with the correct environmental variables?

Comment: I updated the question but I am not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: If you don't want the variable exposed in the script or repo, hold the variables in the image and pull from a private repo. Alternatively, use a key vault.

Comment: It means that I cannot use the environment variables from the container using bash script ?

Comment: So you want to extract the variables from the container and use them locally?

Comment: I want to run that : docker-compose exec apache bash -c "\
    printenv | grep BLACKFIRE\
    && blackfire-agent --register --server-id=$BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID --server-token=$BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN \
    && /etc/init.d/blackfire-agent restart"

Comment: You don't usually use init scripts in Docker; if you need to restart the process running in the container you'd restart the whole container.  The environment variables and any other settings you'd need to launch it should be in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Usually the repo has a place for secret keys...

Comment: Please forget about repo as it is not the core of my question. Tell me how can I use env variable with docker exec. If it is not possible please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The code repository usually has a function to store secret keys and environment tokens.  For instance, github secrets can be kept in `https://github.com/`*`user`*`/`*`repo`*`/settings/secrets/actions` for your actions or `https://github.com/`*`user`*`/`*`repo`*`/settings/secrets/codespaces/new` for the repo.

Comment: It means that it is impossible to use env variables with docker exec ?

Comment: That is not as secure as defining the key variables on the build system.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the use of " (double quotes) that made the string to be interpreted not by the container but by the machine running the docker exec. This machine did not have the env variables as they are set in the container.

Replace with ' (simple quotes) make the script to use the environment variables set in the container.

```
docker-compose exec apache bash -c '\
   blackfire-agent --register --server-id=$BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID --server-token=$BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN \
   && /etc/init.d/blackfire-agent restart'
```